# Cannot get the urls filtered from JSON response using PowerShell

Tags: json, powershell, parsing

I have JSON raw content in a file. I am trying parse urls using ConvertFrom-Json. somehow it does not work. ideas are greatly appreciated.

```
$file1 = "C:\Test\output1.txt"
$file2 = "C:\Test\output2.txt"

$content = Get-Content $file1
$response = ConvertFrom-Json $content
$urls = $response.input | where {$_.url}
$urls | Out-File $file2
```

Raw content in output1 file is :

```
{"workitems":[{"Inputs":{"url":"http://www.cmha.ca/news-and-events/news/?70301308070201301010","c":"1"},"Outputs":{"ip":"50.56.166.145","latencymilliseconds":"785","httpstatuscode":"200","completeresponse":"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nVary: ......etc}}]}
```

The file is about the size 10K KB. How best we can parse and just get the Urls to output2.txt file ?

Answer (score 0):

Running the following code

```
$file1 = "file1.txt"
$content = Get-Content $file1
$response = ConvertFrom-JSON $content
$urls = $response.workitems.inputs | where {$_.url}
$urls.url
```

**Outputs**

http://www.cmha.ca/news-and-events/news/?70301308070201301010

Comment: my bad, it was copy paste error but I have used 'inputs' but system throwing the error :  Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'InputObject'.

Comment: @SunRays add `-Raw` to `Get-Content`

Comment: Thank you very much the -Raw for Get-Content worked very well. I have also added square brackets before and after the JSON Response, cause ConvertFrom-JSON does not like JSON that does not contain opening and closing square brackets [ ] and mine doesn't output with []. Thank you all for the help.